# Calling Google APIs from within k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

According to "[Finding credentials automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#finding_credentials_automatically)" from Google Cloud:

> ...ADC (Application Default Credentials) is able to implicitly find the credentials as long as the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is set, **or as long as the application is running on** Compute Engine, **GKE**, App Engine, or Cloud Functions.

Do I understand correctly that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` does not need to be present, if I want to call Google Cloud APIs in current Google Cloud project?

Let's say I'm in a container in a pod, what can I do from within acontainer to test that calling Google Cloud APIs just work™?

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity for how to up permissions for your pods. You have to do some mapping a so Google knows which pods get which perks, but after that it’s auto-magic as you mentioned. Otherwise calls will use the node-level google permissions which are generally minimal.